# Not able to validate confirm password using angularJS2

Tags: angular

I want to check whether the password enter matches the confirm password text using angularJS2 but I am not able to validate it.
the following is my code

```
 this.userForm = this.fb.group({
            'username': [this.users.username, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(4),
                Validators.maxLength(24)
            ]
            ],
            'gender': [this.users.username, [Validators.required]],
            'password': [this.users.password, [Validators.required]],
            'confirmPassword': [this.users.password, Validators.required]
        }, { validation: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmPassword') });

 matchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, confirmPasswordKey: string) {
        return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
            let password = group.controls[passwordKey];
            let confirmPassword = group.controls[confirmPasswordKey];
            if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
                return {
                    mismatchedPasswords: true
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

I have gone through various document and as per the document, the function **mismatchedPasswords** gets called when we we access the password or the confirm password element but in my code this method is not getting called. Am i missing something?

I have included the following files

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a New class for custom validation as below

```
      export class ValidationService {
      static getValidatorErrorMessage(validatorName: string, validatorValue?: any) {
      let config = {
      'mismatch': 'Password Mismatch.',
    };
      return config[validatorName];
    }
static comparePassword(control) {
    if (control.value) {
      if (control.root.get('passwordKey').value != control.root.get('confirmPasswordKey').value)
        return {'mismatch': true};
    }
  }

}
```

Below is your updated form group

```
import {ValidationService} from "point to yourlocation/validation.service";
  this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  'username': [this.users.username, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(4),
    Validators.maxLength(24)
  ]
  ],
  'gender': [this.users.username, [Validators.required]],
  'password': [this.users.password, [Validators.required]],
  'confirmPassword': [this.users.password, [Validators.required, ValidationService.passwordValidator]]
})
```

Below is the validation error, put it where you need to display error

```
<md-hint align="start">
  <control-messages [control]="userForm .get('confirmPassword')"></control-messages>
</md-hint>
```

Finally, below is the component to fetch your error message according to return type

```
   import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {ValidationService} from " poin to ur location/validation.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'control-messages',
  template: `<div class="field-error" *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ValidationComponent {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  constructor() { }

  get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && (this.control.dirty || this.control.touched)) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```